# How format Date time using DateTimePicker and get the selected date as String?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried using this=> `choosenFromCalender = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(newValue);`

but the for this error not able to format properly.

[image]

```
  DateTimePicker(
                           
                            dateMask: 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                            initialValue: DateTime.now().toString(),
                            type: DateTimePickerType.date,
                            firstDate: DateTime(1800),
                            lastDate: DateTime(2050),                                
                            onChanged: (newValue) {
                              print(newValue);  // for now its `2022-07-27` i want `27-07-2022`
                            
                            },

                            onSaved: (value) {

                            },
                          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to formate picked date

for that you need to put below code in onChanged method

```
newValue=DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(DateTime.parse(newValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

The Issue is that you get from the `newValue` a string back, but DateFormat can only handle DateTime formats. What you can do is, that you parse your String to a DateTime object.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.parse(newValue);
```

The `dt` object you can use then to Format your DateTime.

But there is an better alternative. You can do both operations together.

```
 print(DateFormat('dd-MM-YYYY').parse(newValue));
```

Prints you the Formatted Date as you want with the value from the onChanged Method